# Do SVG links respect the nofollow attribute?

Tags: svg, hyperlink

Do SVG links respect the rel="nofollow" attribute (so if I add rel="nofollow" will Google recognise it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In SVG 1.1 the only supported attribute is [target](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/linking.html#Links).
- SVG 2 adds [lots more attributes including rel](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/linking.html#Links)

Browsers are gradually implementing SVG 2. I'm not aware of any that have implemented this part of SVG 2 yet though.

Comment: I suppose the question should have been: If I put the rel="nofollow" attribute on will Google respect it and not count that link?

Comment: Google will never see it if the browser does not support it.

Comment: But I can see it if I view-source in Chrome/FF/IE11. Wouldn't Google get the same source?

Comment: Not view-source sorry, if I inspect the link.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in my previous comments that the answer to that is **no**